# using preg_replace to replace a <br />

Tags: php, preg-replace

I've read a few articles on preg_replace and still don't understand what all the weird ]{!('/)[ characters mean.

Basically, I want to find the first instance of a break `<br />`, and replace it with a `</strong><br />`

Code I have: `preg_replace('<br />', '</strong><br />', nl2br($row['n_message']), 1)`

but I know I'm missing something in how I declare the strings `<br />` and `</strong>`.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You're missing delimiters, and lenience for HTML weirdness (`<br> <BR> <BR /> <br/> <BR/>...`), and the Accept button on your previous questions.

Comment: The "weird characters" is [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) syntax.

Comment: You can learn about regular expressions (which is what you need for `preg_replace`) on http://regular-expression.info/ and the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace <br> to new line between pre tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028322/replace-br-to-new-line-between-pre-tag) (Remember: You can always find a better answer if you try the search function yourself!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Regular Expressions**

The only thing you are missing is a delimiter in your regexp pattern. I believe this can be any character; a common choice is a forward slash. But then of course you must escape your existing forward slashes. Here are two examples, using forward slash and right square bracket.

```
$text = preg_replace('/<br \/>/', '</strong><br />', nl2br($text), 1);
$text = preg_replace(']<br />]', '</strong><br />', nl2br($text), 1);
```

**Alternative**

I agree with michaeljdennis that you should use `str_replace` in this case. `preg_replace` is appropriate for fancy replacements, but not one as simple as this.

However, `str_replace` does **not** have a $limit argument. If you wish to limit the number of replacements to the first instance, do something like

```
// Split the string into two pieces, before and after the first <br />
$str_parts = explode('<br />', $row['message'], 2);

// Append the closing strong tag to the first piece
$str_parts[0] .= '</strong>';

// Glue the pieces back together with the <br /> tag
$row['message'] = implode('<br />', $str_parts);
```

Comment: thanks for the help. I was trying to be efficient by doing it with one function but at least I understand what this is doing.

Comment: I updated my answer with a preg_replace option. You were basically only missing 2-3 characters.

Comment: `/<br\s*?\/?>/` if you want to replace all variants: `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br />`, `<br        />`

Answer (score 2):

The weird characters you're referring to are regular expression patterns I assume.